# Determine source of iOS app store downloads?

Tags: ios

Every few months, I randomly get a huge spike in downloads for one of my iOS apps on the app store. This spike usually only last 1-3 days. I've looked at the analytics provided by Itunes Connect but at the most it shows that there is a spike in searches on the app store for my app. I've googled my app's name and website to see if there have been any blog posts, but nothing substantial turns.

My question is, how can I find the source of this spike in searches/downloads?

Comment: Better fit on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Configure a proxy server to handle your traffic.  If you're using a windows an easy proxy server to use is fiddler.  Once you've installed fiddler on your machine, you can configure it to accept remote connections:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorRemoteMachine

If you really want the nitty gritty you can configure it to decyprt the HTTPS requests as well:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Then you'll want to import the root certificate that's generated by fiddler.  Use the button "export root certificate to desktop" pictured in the first screen shot on "Configure Fiddler to Decrypt HTTPS Traffic" page.

You can then email that certificate to an email account configured on your phone, or host it on a secure webserver that you can access on your phone.  Emailing is probably the easiest option.

Make sure you also open the firewall on your PC for the port where the proxy server is listening.  Then configure the WiFi connection on your iphone (assuming you're using WiFi @ home, right?) to use the new fiddler proxy.

Go to settings -> wifi -> click on your wifi -> configure proxy (at the bottom)
Select manual.  The server is the IP for the PC that's running fiddler, and the port is the port # where fiddler is listening, default 8888 I believe.

Once you have this configured, you'll see all of the HTTP/HTTPS requests logged in fiddler.  If it becomes too much, you can use the filters to filter traffic from/to certain hosts, among other available filters.  You can also start/stop the logging and clear the logs.  You can even delete individual requests from the logs, or highlight large groups and delete en masse.

Good luck and happy hunting!

Comment: Wow, after I typed this up I realized that you have an app ON the app store that's being downloaded and you want to track the download for for YOUR app...  Maybe spike in traffic probably coincides with some scheduled updates?